# Creating InDesign "Paragraph / Character Style" shortcuts on a Mac wireless keyboard w/o number pad

Tags: macos, keyboard

Creating InDesign "Paragraph / Character Style" shortcuts on a Mac wireless keyboard w/o number pad.

Does someone have a fix for this problem? …or still is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Use the app **Karabiner** (https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).
It can remap **fn + number** to **fn + numpad number**. 
With **Shift+fn+1** you have **Shift+Num 1**.
It works.